# Is it possible to instantiate an empty object in Javascript but define its structure with nested Flow types?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype

Imagine I have a set of Flow types like this:

```
type Planet = {
  diameter: number,
  mass: number,
  name: string,
  countries: Array<Country>
}

type Country = {
  area: number,
  population: number,
  name: string,
  cities: Array<City>
}

type City = {
  population: number,
  name: string
}
```

Given this nested structure, is there an easy way to instantiate an object called `planet` that will automatically include a `Country` child and a `City` grandchild?

Comment: What have you tried? Is it giving you any problems?

Comment: your type declarations are correct, if you want to instantiate an object then declare it as classes

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used Flow before but you'd do this just as you would in Typescript

```js
const earth: Planet = {
  diameter: 1,
  mass: 1,
  name: "Earth",
  countries: [{
    area: 268020,
    population: 4886000,
    name: "New Zealand",
    cities: [{
      population: 212700,
      name: "Wellington"
    }]
  }]
}
```

[Flow Demo](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAKMAhgHZ4ZgC8YA3qmGACYCWJAtpXgE4BcYMgFcOAI14AaRmA4kAznIHCxk6WU54BcjD1ZkA5lKYBjOELI7WeRWACCPHiSwAeAMJmLPLAD5UAX3RsfDB3cx0sGnppEh48EiURcR4jMBw4HCFSDFY4MgSVZLUNLUsDFONWbOsBe0cXV0qff0DcAgbsSIYmNIysnLzBRNUmdS4S3QNm1FMybTA4ngwACwFickpO6TYNDF4BAEYU2QUDlNHNMAAiAFEY5cvyj0tqsABtLqYwGLiBACYANgAHAAGX7AlLddKZEjZXICAAsgMB-2BqIhgmKVwAcngkAAtOKkMjMB7SEyVKw2d5kz49aGwga-fa-ADsaJpI0xlwA6ngYDA9PoMLlLjS-ABdaQS-xAA)

Answer (score 1):

Flow is just for typing - it says nothing about your actual object definition or constructors.  You can simply create an object in-line, and even just have an empty array of countries (thats still valid as an array type).

```
/* @flow */


type Planet = {
  diameter: number,
  mass: number,
  name: string,
  countries: Array<Country>
}

type Country = {
  area: number,
  population: number,
  name: string,
  cities: Array<City>
}

type City = {
  population: number,
  name: string
}

function foo(): Planet {
  const example = {
    diameter: 1,
    name: 'Pluto',
    mass: 100,
    countries: [],
  };
  return example;
}
```

[Flow example](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAodAXAngBwKZgAKMAhgHZ4ZgC8YA3qmGACYCWJAtpXgE4BcYMgFcOAI14AaRmA4kAznIHCxk6WU54BcjD1ZkA5lKYBjOELI7WeRWACCPHiSwAeAMJmLPLAD5UAX0xcAndzHSwaemkSHjwSJRFxHiMwHDgcIVIMVjgyeJUktQ0tSwNk41Ys6wF7RxdXCp9-QPwweuwIhiZU9Mzs3MEE1SZ1LmLdAybUKHNjLJywKDg4AAoASgFickpIkxztMDwAD04cGAJaTqYWdi4MXgEARmThorAAcmIhDDg355l5GwPAAMQL+plCuiqYAA2gBdZJ+ADc0hiGCEPDIB2OHFOeGRASAA)